# How to set a sheet's number of rows and columns at creation time? (And a word about Google's "advanced parameters")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When creating a spreadsheet *ex novo*, Google's SpreadsheetApp allows one to specify the number of rows and columns of said spreadsheet:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(name, rows, columns);
```

This only applies to the first sheet that comes within the newly created spreadsheet.

What I need to do is to replicate this behaviour when inserting a new sheet inside an existing spreadsheet. Apparently there is no explicit way to do this.

The only clue is, the function that creates a new sheet

```
var sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(options);
```

Optionally takes this mysterious parameter, `options`, which is not ever described anywhere except [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(Object)), where Google states that this "advanced parameters" object can be use to duplicate the sheet from a template.

There appears to be no documentation about this object anywhere else. These advanced parameters for sheet creation are only mentioned there.

Summing up, the questions are:

1. How to set the number of **rows** and **columns** of a new sheet, created inside of an **existing spreadsheet**, programmatically, without creating and cloning other spreadsheets or using a template, and so on.
2. What on earth are those **advanced parameters**? I'd really like to read any documentation about these: if they exist, they may even be useful for something! (Or at least usable...)

Comment: The only `options` I've been able to locate are `template: templateSheet`. this copies all data the template sheet object to the new sheet. The sheet template must be one of the sheets of the Spreadsheet object. Try either creating a template sheet in your spreadsheet or using an active sheet as the template and seeing what happens.

Comment: I have to programmatically create this new spreadsheets with many sheets in variyng sizes inside. In my scenario, speed is an issue. If it was not like that, I would have just kept and cloned big template files, or created whole spreadsheets on the fly and merged those. Unluckily, these kind of operations, make apps-script just comically slow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the restrictions you've imposed ("and so on") it's not possible to answer your question. The options are to start with a template spreadsheet that has all the sheets you want, clone existing sheets already in the spreadsheet, or add new sheets then expand or trim them to the size you want.

#### Utility function

Assuming it's OK to use the last option, here's a utility function that handles a variety of ways to insert a new sheet.

```js
/**
 * Wrapper for Spreadsheet.insertSheet() method to support customization.
 * All parameters are optional & positional.
 *
 * @param {String}  sheetName     Name of new sheet (defaults to "Sheet #")
 * @param {Number}  sheetIndex    Position for new sheet (default 0 means "end")
 * @param {Number}  rows          Vertical dimension of new sheet (default 0 means "system default", 1000)
 * @param {Number}  columns       Horizontal dimension of new sheet (default 0 means "system default", 26)
 * @param {String}  template      Name of existing sheet to copy (default "" means none)
 *
 * @returns {Sheet}               Sheet object for chaining.
 */
function insertSheet( sheetName, sheetIndex, rows, columns, template ) {
  
  // Check parameters, set defaults
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var numSheets = ss.getSheets().length;
  sheetIndex = sheetIndex || (numSheets + 1);
  sheetName = sheetName || "Sheet " + sheetIndex;
  var options = template ? { 'template' : ss.getSheetByName(template) } : {};
  
  // Will throw an exception if sheetName already exists
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName, sheetIndex, options);
 
  if (rows !== 0) {
    // Adjust dimension: rows
    var newSheetRows = newSheet.getMaxRows();
    
    if (rows < newSheetRows) {
      // trim rows
      newSheet.deleteRows(rows+1, newSheetRows-rows);
    }
    else if (rows > newSheetRows) {
      // add rows
      newSheet.insertRowsAfter(newSheetRows, rows-newSheetRows);
    }
  }
  
  if (columns !== 0) {
    // Adjust dimension: columns
    var newSheetColumns = newSheet.getMaxColumns();
    
    if (columns < newSheetColumns) {
      // trim columns
      newSheet.deleteColumns(columns+1, newSheetColumns-columns);
    }
    else if (columns > newSheetColumns) {
      // add columns
      newSheet.insertColumnsAfter(newSheetColumns,columns-newSheetColumns);
    }
  }
  
  // Return new Sheet object
  return newSheet;
}
```

#### Examples & Performance

You expressed concern about slow performance; below are some observations from the Execution Transcript of single scenarios. The time needed to tweak dimensions is not significantly more than the time for inserting a default sheet.

Insertion of a default sheet:

```js
insertSheet();
```

This script takes no more than 200ms (and most of that is just `Spreadsheet.insertSheet()`):

```js
[15-11-18 15:56:25:365 EST] Starting execution
[15-11-18 15:56:25:369 EST] SpreadsheetApp.getActive() [0 seconds]
[15-11-18 15:56:25:390 EST] Spreadsheet.getSheets() [0.02 seconds]
[15-11-18 15:56:25:544 EST] Spreadsheet.insertSheet([Sheet 2, 2, {}]) [0.153 seconds]
[15-11-18 15:56:25:565 EST] Sheet.getMaxRows() [0.02 seconds]
[15-11-18 15:56:25:565 EST] Sheet.getMaxColumns() [0 seconds]
[15-11-18 15:56:25:597 EST] Execution succeeded [0.196 seconds total runtime]
```

Inserting a sheet at a specific index with 10 rows and 10 columns (smaller than default):

```js
insertSheet("New sheet",1, 10, 10);
```

This takes about 325ms:

```js
[15-11-18 15:59:54:476 EST] Starting execution
[15-11-18 15:59:54:481 EST] SpreadsheetApp.getActive() [0 seconds]
[15-11-18 15:59:54:520 EST] Spreadsheet.getSheets() [0.038 seconds]
[15-11-18 15:59:54:595 EST] Spreadsheet.insertSheet([New sheet, 1, {}]) [0.075 seconds]
[15-11-18 15:59:54:629 EST] Sheet.getMaxRows() [0.033 seconds]
[15-11-18 15:59:54:699 EST] Sheet.deleteRows([11, 990]) [0.069 seconds]
[15-11-18 15:59:54:746 EST] Sheet.getMaxColumns() [0.046 seconds]
[15-11-18 15:59:54:809 EST] Sheet.deleteColumns([11, 16]) [0.062 seconds]
[15-11-18 15:59:54:810 EST] Execution succeeded [0.329 seconds total runtime]
```

And finally, inserting a sheet at a specific index with 2000 rows and 52 columns (both twice default):

```js
insertSheet("Big Sheet",1, 2000, 52);
```

Which takes about 240ms:

```js
[15-11-18 16:09:36:393 EST] Starting execution
[15-11-18 16:09:36:398 EST] SpreadsheetApp.getActive() [0 seconds]
[15-11-18 16:09:36:419 EST] Spreadsheet.getSheets() [0.02 seconds]
[15-11-18 16:09:36:491 EST] Spreadsheet.insertSheet([Big Sheet, 1, {}]) [0.071 seconds]
[15-11-18 16:09:36:518 EST] Sheet.getMaxRows() [0.027 seconds]
[15-11-18 16:09:36:563 EST] Sheet.insertRowsAfter([1000, 1000]) [0.044 seconds]
[15-11-18 16:09:36:585 EST] Sheet.getMaxColumns() [0.021 seconds]
[15-11-18 16:09:36:645 EST] Sheet.insertColumnsAfter([26, 26]) [0.059 seconds]
[15-11-18 16:09:36:646 EST] Execution succeeded [0.247 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: This is the way to go. Trimming and extending is actually very fast, so no concerns for speed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One option to consider would be to think about it from the opposite direction as you are proposing: Instead of creating a sheet with x columns and y rows, create a sheet with the default number of columns/rows and use the `sheet.deleteColumns(columnPosition, howMany)` and `sheet.deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)` methods to define the sheet size.

Your code would be something like:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(name, rows, columns);
var myNumColumns = ____; //or defined in the function call
var newSheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName, sheetIndex, options);
var columnsToDelete = newSheet.getLastColumn() - myNumColumns;
newSheet.deleteColumns((myNumColumns-1), columnsToDelete);
```

You would probably have to create a custom menu function or add on interface to do this if you want the end-users to create it for themselves since you can't really create a trigger off of adding a new sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [getLastColumn](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) will not work as this just gets the last column with content in it. You want [getMaxColumns](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxcolumns) instead. You can follow the links to get more detailed info on the difference.

Something like:

```
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openByID(FILEID_HERE);
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEETNAMEHERE);
var deleteColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns - sheet.getLastColumn; 

sheet.deleteColumns((sheet.getLastColumn() +1),deleteColumns);
```

In this sample, `deleteColumns` would be equal to the total number of columns minus the number of columns that have content in them. Then, in the next line, you set `sheet.deleteColumns(start column, how many columns)`.

It looks like this might be sunset soon though, in which case you could use the `.deleteColumn(columnPosition)` command and a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Google Sheets API service and then use the code below to resize the sheet in one simple API call.

[image]

```
 const sheetId = {your sheet id}
 const spreadsheetId = {your spreadsheet id}

 Sheets.Spreadsheets?.batchUpdate(
      {
        requests: [
          {
            updateSheetProperties: {
              fields: 'gridProperties',
              properties: {
                sheetId: sheetId,
                gridProperties: {
                  columnCount: 40, // required column count
                  rowCount: 20, // required row count
                },
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      spreadsheetId
    )
```